# Traefik installation on Google Kubernetes Engine using Helm results in init:CrashLoopBackOff state. How can I resolve this?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm, traefik

Install traefik 2.9 on KGE with helm

I have a problem using helm to install traefik in my cluster that I have on Google Cloud.
Basically when I use the initcontainer to go and change the permissions in the certificate folder of the persistent volume I get an access denied error.

this is my values for traefik helm

```
persistence:
  enabled: true
  name: ssldata
  accessMode: ReadWriteOnce
  size: 1Gi
  path: /ssldata
podSecurityContext:
  fsGroup: null

deployment: 
  initContainers: # Ensure the `/data/acme.json` Permisssion is 600
    - name: fix-data-dir-permissions
      image: alpine:3.16.2
      command: ["sh", "-c", "touch /ssldata/acme.json; chmod -v 600 /ssldata/acme.json"]
      securityContext:
        runAsNonRoot: true
        runAsGroup: 65532
        runAsUser: 65532      
      volumeMounts:
        - name: ssldata
          mountPath: /ssldata
```

when helm finishes deploying the traefick pod remains in the state of init:CrashLoopBackOff

Looking at the pod creation logs here is what I read:
**touch: /ssldata/acme.json: Permission denied**

Answer (score 0):

According to this: https://github.com/traefik/traefik-helm-chart/issues/396, you should try:

```
  command: 
    [
      "sh",
      "-c",
      "touch /data/acme.json; chown 65532 /data/acme.json; chmod -v 600 /data/acme.json",
    ]
  securityContext:
    runAsNonRoot: false
    runAsGroup: 0
    runAsUser: 0
```

Where you create the file as root user, and change the ownership to 65532 after that.